# Is there a way to undefine and redefine a class of a class loader?

Tags: java, classloader

Is there a way to undefine and redefine a class of a class loader with another runtime compiled class?

Comment: The first approach would be to take a look at how some default classloader registers loaded classes. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, they use the defineClass method, but I have not found an undefine method

Comment: What if you simply call `defineClass` again with a different `byte[]` parameter?

Comment: I tried, but when I call it for the second time I obtain an exception that tell that the class is already defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't a way to undefine a class and redefine it.

The closest you can get to this is to create a new classloader and use it to load a new version of the class.  This is how "hot loading" is implemented.

However, what you are actually doing is creating a new type, from the perspective of the Java runtime type system.  (The JLS says that two classes with the same fully-qualified names and different class loaders are different types.)

Notes:

- Having multiple versions of a type at the same time can lead to unintuitive runtime type errors.
- You need to be careful about the relationship between the 2 class loaders.  If the new one has the old one as a parent, things would get rather messed up.
- This kind of thing can lead to some rather obscure memory leaks.  While `Class` and `ClassLoader` objects can be garbage collected, there are some complex (hidden) dependencies between classloaders, classes and instances that mean that a single reachable instance can cause a classloader and all of its loaded classes remain reachable.

---

Why is there no way to do it?

One reason is that is there was, it would blow a massive whole in the JVM's runtime type security.  Consider the following sequence.

1. Load the following class

   ```
     public class Sneaky {
         public long x = 42;
     }
   ```
2. Create an instance

   ```
     Sneaky s = new Sneaky();
   ```
3. Redefine the class to a new version

   ```
     public class Sneaky {
         public String x;
     }
   ```
4. Try to use the `x` field of the object we created before.

   ```
     System.out.println(s.x.length());
   ```

   Something very bad would happen ....

Comment: I also tried to clear the private classes vector inside the classloader but I obtain the same result

Comment: I am not surprised.  But you should not have tried it anyway; see my "why is there n way?" explanation.  If you had succeeded you could cause seemingly random JVM panics / crashes.

Comment: It should be noted that if the redefined class is only different from the original class in the contents of `Code` attributes, (meaning that all fields and even all method prototypes stay the same,) then the JVM should be considering it as a compatible class change and allowing it. Alas, it doesn't.

Comment: Mike.  That is incorrect.  Java defines the identity of a class to be its fully qualified name + the classloader that loaded it.  What you are suggesting is *expressly* contradicted by the Java specs.  It is not an implementation restriction.  It is *by design*.  (And I can think of reasons why your idea would break type abstraction.)